# how to use: - (void) saveErrorHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))errorCallback;

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I've got a function from Magical Record that i'm trying to use. However I don't understand how to use the error handler part

the function is:
- (void) saveErrorHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))errorCallback;

I don't understand the "(void (^)(NSError *))errorCallback" part. I know this is a standard objective c problem. How do i use this function in my code with the errorCallback so i can extract the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [self saveErrorHandler:^(NSError * error) {
    //NSError code handler
}];
```

this is how you implement the function.

Comment: this gives me a "[NSManagedObjectContext saveErrorHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" is there something i'm missing?

Comment: where the is the declaration of the function?

Comment: its in a NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalSaves.h category. I can use the standard "-(void)save" function so i believe its included properly. the header file is here: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObjectContext/NSManagedObjectContext%2BMagicalSaves.h

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Magical Records. The function is declared but nowhere implemented. You can use `MR_saveWithErrorCallback` instead.

Comment: To get it working without the "MR_" you need to #define MR_SHORTHAND 1 before your #import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h". I think this answer is correct. I have another project using magical record that this works in. It looks like my problem is probably the xcode linker not linking the library in properly (it'll probably randomly fix itself after a few reboots like it normally does).